# Capitalizing first word of a book title

Tags: ruby, rspec

Have to make the following test pass:

```
require 'book'

describe Book do

  before do
    @book = Book.new
  end

  describe 'title' do
    it 'should capitalize the first letter' do
      @book.title = "inferno"
      @book.title.should == "Inferno"
    end
```

I'm not sure what I have to do. I have the following code:

```
class Book
@book = Book.new
def title
    x = @book
    y = x.split("")
    y[0] = y[0].upcase
    z = y.join("")
    z
end

end
```

but it won't pass, what am I supposed to do?

Comment: "_It won't pass_" is not an adequate problem report. What data did you feed in? What results were you expecting? What did you actually get? What steps have you taken to try and fix the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write customized `Book#title=` and `Book#title` methods to pass the RSpec tests.

```
class Book
  def title=(t)
    @title = t.capitalize
  end

  def title
    @title
  end
end
```